# How to have tail -f show colored output

Tags: command-line, colors, alias, highlighting, tail

I'd like to be able to tail the output of a server log file that has messages like:

```
INFO
SEVERE
```

etc, and if it's `SEVERE`, show the line in red; if it's `INFO`, in green.  What kind of alias can I setup for a `tail` command that would help me do this?

Comment: one-line `sed`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14691971/52074

Answer (score 282, accepted):

Try out **multitail**¹. This is an übergeneralization of `tail -f`. You can watch multiple files in separate windows, highlight lines based on their content, and more.

```
multitail -c /path/to/log
```

The colors are configurable. If the default color scheme doesn't work for you, write your own in the config file. For example, call `multitail -cS amir_log /path/to/log` with the following `~/.multitailrc`:

```
colorscheme:amir_log
cs_re:green:INFO
cs_re:red:SEVERE
```

Another solution, if you're on a server where it's inconvenient to install non-**standard** tools, is to combine `tail -f` with sed or awk to add color selection control sequences. This requires `tail -f` to flush its standard output without delay even when its standard output is a pipe, I don't know if all implementations do this.

```
tail -f /path/to/log | awk '
  /INFO/ {print "\033[32m" $0 "\033[39m"}
  /SEVERE/ {print "\033[31m" $0 "\033[39m"}
'
```

or with [sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html)

```
tail -f /path/to/log | sed --unbuffered \
    -e 's/\(.*INFO.*\)/\o033[32m\1\o033[39m/' \
    -e 's/\(.*SEVERE.*\)/\o033[31m\1\o033[39m/'
```

If your sed isn't GNU sed, replace `\o033` by a literal escape character and remove `--unbuffered`.

Yet another possibility is to run `tail -f` in an **Emacs** shell buffer and use Emacs's syntax coloring abilities.

¹  <sub>The [historical website](http://www.vanheusden.com/multitail/) vanished in early 2021. The latest version is still available in many distributions, e.g. [Arch](https://archlinux.org/packages/community/x86_64/multitail/), [Debian](https://packages.debian.org/sid/multitail).</sub>

Comment: how can you do this with `sed`? (sorry for being lazy and not figuring it out myself!) But would you please add a `sed` example as well.

Comment: @Ali Sed is less convenient because it doesn't have a syntax for the escape character, you need to have it literally in the script or use a shell quoting method to work it in. I recommend that you use awk.

Comment: @Gilles Thank you for sharing your knowledge. Though, is there a way to do this with *vim* as like *Emacs* does?

Comment: @Gilles In your `tail -f` with `awk` code, if a string doesn't have *INFO* and *SEVERE*, the string isn't be printed. How can I print the *remain* strings either? (The string doesn't need to be colored)

Comment: @Benjamin Add `; next` before the closing braces to skip further processing, and a new processing line `1 {print}` at the end (`1` means always).

Comment: It works different to ccze and colortail in the way that each line is colored according to keywords (instead of terms, like: hostname, date-time,IP address, etc). For example, "SEVERE" keyword will make the whole line with red background and white  text color. Using the default color scheme, looks very saturated of colors. Its better if you try it.

Comment: the awk version worked well for what I needed. And on an XServe. thx

Comment: I have a syntax error at `[` for the `awk` version.

Comment: For `sed`, the problem is that it uses buffer, so I don't see the content appearing until the buffer is full. I've added `--unbuffered`.

Comment: @OndraŽižka Only if you pipe it into something else, otherwise it's line-buffered.

Comment: `sed --unbuffered -e 's/\(.*FATAL.*\)/\o033[1;31m\1\o033[0;39m/' -e 's/\(.*ERROR.*\)/\o033[31m\1\o033[39m/' -e 's/\(.*WARN.*\)/\o033[33m\1\o033[39m/' -e 's/\(.*INFO.*\)/\o033[32m\1\o033[39m/' -e 's/\(.*DEBUG.*\)/\o033[34m\1\o033[39m/' -e 's/\(.*TRACE.*\)/\o033[30m\1\o033[39m/' -e 's/\(.*[Ee]xception.*\)/\o033[1;39m\1\o033[0;39m/'`

Comment: My version of `sed` doesn't accept `--unbuffered`. Nor does it accept `\oNNN` sequences. For the latter, I had to use embedded `printf`s like [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/140255)

Comment: How to modify `awk` to only add color to the string SEVERE?

Comment: The URL for `multitail` no longer works, and the site no longer maintains a valid certificate.

Comment: Providing a full example of awk from @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' 6/29/12 comment:
`tail -f /some/log | awk '/INFO/ {print "\033[32m" $0 "\033[39m"; next}
1{print}'`

Answer (score 164):

[**grc**](http://korpus.juls.savba.sk/~garabik/software/grc.html), the generic colourizer is pretty cool.

```
apt-get install grc
```

Just do

```
grc tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log
```

and enjoy!

You’ll also find it on [GitHub](https://github.com/garabik/grc).

Comment: This is exactly what I needed: lightweight and simple. The coloring isn't exactly right for my log types (custom logs) but any coloring makes it easier for me to follow a log.

Comment: For me 'grc' on Debian errors out with: OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied. Also it depends on Python being installed so it's not relaly lightweight unless you already have it. I have found 'ccze' to work much better, ex. 'tail -f -n 50 /var/log/starbound-server.log | ccze -A'.

Comment: grc default settings in Ubuntu didn't display nice for syslogs or mail.log. It is not easy to understand how to customize it.

Comment: I found it quicker and easier way to colorize than multitail. Just did a quick install via source on my CentOS system and upgraded my life. Will install on my other systems too.

Comment: This looks pretty terrible on nginx logs http://i.imgur.com/aJbIOfL.png

Comment: when working with multiple distro (debian, gentoo, fedora, etc), grc was the one that fit the bill (some distros don't come with mtail and/or multitail).  Though I must say that performance wise, grcat hogs a lot more CPU than multitail.  But, when I use tmux/screen and have a split/vsplit windows, multitail requires window dimensions while grc does not (i.e I like to 'tail -F' and/or 'dmesg --follow' in bottom window while looking at server issue live).  Pros-and-cons weighed, grc wins for me...

Comment: You can customize how it colors by passing in a configuration file, which should allow you to fix things that dont look great. Nice tool!

Comment: Didn't work at all on my Ubuntu 18

Comment: This is on Homebrew for mac as well. Worked like a charm!

Comment: Works like a charm on Raspberry Pi 4 running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS arm64 .

Comment: easy, works as advertised!

Comment: would this work with cat ? I tried on my python logs , It didn't

Answer (score 55):

Have you had a look at [ccze](http://pwet.fr/man/linux/commandes/ccze)? You have the possibility to customize the default colors of some keywords using the option `-c` or directly in your configuration file. If your screen is clearing after colorizing you must use option `-A`.

**Edit:**

If you really would like to have the complete line colored in red, you could also have a try at the following:

```
$ tail -f myfile.log | perl -pe 's/.*SEVERE.*/\e[1;31m$&\e[0m/g'
```

`\e[1;31m` will give you the red color. If you would like some yellow, use `\e[1;33m`, and for green use `\e[1;32m`.  The `\e[0m` restores the normal text color.

Comment: This doesn't work on Mac - I'm upvoting it because it works on Linux.

Comment: Upvoting because while the perl/ansi trick might not, ccze does.

Comment: You can also make your terminal send an alert or "beep" by adding `\007` to the end of the regex, like so: `perl -pe 's/(ERROR)/\033[31m$1\033[0m\007/g;'`. This works awesome if you are using tmux with `set -g bell-action any`, in which case if you have your log tailing in another window, that window name will alert whenever the regex finds a match.

Comment: @AmirAfghani This is a linux/unix SE site, therefore I am not sure why you thought it would work on mac.

Comment: @BЈовић Mac is a Unix.

Comment: +1 ccze works fine for most cases out of the box. I wouldn't recommend it if you want to customize further the way it display some keywords ("-c" option didn't work for me) or patterns. If you normally monitor few kinds of logs, I would recommend using colortail and add your own customized patterns (it is RegEx based, but it is easy to customize it even if you don't know RegEx).

Comment: If I leave `ccze` running for several days it will eventually hang and all output will be buffered and not printed to the screen.  Really frustrating and makes it unusable.

Comment: can anyone explain if the suggested tail+perl pair is somehow buffering the output? sometimes i do not see the final line(s) of the log when piping to perl part... how can i avoid buffering? thanks

Comment: In my environment grep is not accepting --color, so I used that idea to create it on my own - `grep $1 | perl -pe 's/'$1'/\e[1;31m$&\e[0m/g'` in my script...

Comment: CCZE works on Mac! Just tried installing with `brew install ccze` and the result works: `tail -f -n 500 /private/var/log/system.log | ccze`

Comment: this works on Mac - mojave

Answer (score 51):

Have a look at [lnav](http://lnav.org), the advanced log file viewer.

[image: lnav]
[image: lnav]

It can also pretty print various formats.

Before:

[image: lnav-before-pretty]

After:

[image: lnav-pretty]

Comment: Thanks @bagonyi, it's a great tool indeed. It provide a query tool using SQL statements  like `select log_time, log_level, log_body from syslog_log where log_body like '%CPU%'`

Comment: Available in Fedora

Comment: Amazing tool. The shortcuts to go to previous/next error and also to move 1h back and forth is incredibly useful.

Answer (score 32):

You can use [rainbow](https://github.com/nicoulaj/rainbow), which colorizes lines based on regular expressions:

```
rainbow --red='SEVERE.*' --green='INFO.*' tail -f my-file.log
```

It also comes bundled with [predefined configs](https://github.com/nicoulaj/rainbow/tree/master/rainbow/config/builtin), for example for Tomcat logs:

```
rainbow --config=tomcat tail -f my-file.log
```

(disclaimer: I am the author)

Comment: I tried most of the other solutions offered to this question, but rainbow was the only one that worked equally well on sun, aix, linux, termux, darwin, and cygwin -- the 6(!) environments I use on a daily basis.  All the others involved difficult non-portable build processes for at least some platforms.

Comment: It's my nearly-perfect tool but I don't get the "last line" of an ongoing `tail -f`. Particularly `rainbow --red=CRITICAL tail -f var/log/dev.log` works perfect but `tail -f var/log/dev.log | rainbow --red=CRITICAL` does the bug. Should I open an issue in github?

Answer (score 19):

You can use [colortail](https://github.com/joakim666/colortail):

```
colortail -f /var/log/messages
```

Comment: +1 available at Ubuntu repositories. What I like of colortail compared to ccze is that you can customize freely your patterns using RegEx. 
Available colors: 
black, brightblack, white, brightwhite, magenta, brightmagenta, cyan, brightcyan, green,‌​brightgreen, yellow, brightyellow, red,brightred, blue, brightblue.

Unfortunately there is no way to set bold or other colors like orange.

Comment: I would like to correct one point about my previous comment: "bright"+color includes "bold" (some colors will actually look brighter as well)

Comment: I tried this on Ubuntu 18 and it did not work. The setup is multi-step and instructions are ambiguous. Still unsure that's the part I got wrong; the last part can get clearer "After that you may want to copy and edit the example config files to some
other place. I have them in ~/.colortail/"

Comment: Just install colortail with, `apt install colortail` and it should work without editing ~/.colortail/ too.

Comment: Works like a charm on Ubuntu LTS 20.04 arm64 for Raspberry Pi 4 - apt install colortail gets the job done.

Comment: Even in 2022 with Debian 11, colortail is the simplest solution for color tail files.

Answer (score 13):

Also note that if you just want to look for *one* matching regex, GNU grep with `--color` will work — just pipe your `tail` output through that.

Comment: The OP only wanted to *highlight* the output, not filter it.  Grep won't show non-matching lines...

Comment: If you say `grep  -A9999  -B9999 ` *`regex`*, it will show all lines unless you have 10,000 non-matching lines in a row.  Use something like `GREP_COLORS="ms=31:sl=33:cx=32" grep -A9999 -B9999 SEVERE` to show the word `SEVERE` in red, the rest of SEVERE lines in yellow, and all other (non-SEVERE) lines (up to 9999) in green.

Comment: You might need to pass `--color=always` to grep instead of just `--color`, depending on the order of your pipe, but yes, this works tail (GNU coreutils) 8.27 installed on my box.

Answer (score 11):

To get colored output from standard commands like `grep`, you should set this `alias` in your `.bashrc`

```
# User specific aliases and functions
alias grep='grep --color=auto'
```

when you grep something in your file you see something like this, (but probably in red):

```
[root@linuxbox mydir]# grep "\(INFO\|SEVERE\)" /var/log/logname
this entry is an INFO 
SEVERE this entry is a warn!
this entry is an INFO
this entry is an INFO
SEVERE this entry is a warn!
```

if want to use `tail` or `awk` and want that the color survive to a pipe, then the alias is not enough and you should use the `--color=always` parameter, for example:

```
[root@linubox mydir]# grep --color=always "\(INFO\|SEVERE\)" /var/log/logname | tail -f | awk '{ print $1 }'
this 
SEVERE
this
this
SEVERE
```

If you want color text with `awk` the story is a little bit complex but more powerfull, for example:

```
[root@linubox mydir]# tail -f /var/log/messages | awk '{if ($5 ~ /INFO/) print "\033[1;32m"$0"\033[0m"; else if ($1 ~ /SEVERE/) print "\033[1;31m"$0"\033[0m"; else print $0}'
this entry is an INFO 
SEVERE this entry is a warn!
this is another ENTRY
this entry is an INFO
this is another ENTRY
this entry is an INFO
SEVERE this entry is a warn!
```

with each line in its own color.

There are many other way to get colorized text from shell with other tools and they are well descripted by other members.

Answer (score 7):

I quite like [colorex](https://github.com/Scopart/colorex). Simple, yet satisfying.

```
tail -f /var/log/syslog | colorex -G '[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}' -b $(hostname)
```

Comment: how is that simple?

Comment: @Asclepius fixed (I believe it's the same script)

Answer (score 6):

Based on @uloBasEI answer, I've tried to use `... | perl ... | perl ...`, but Linux pipe gets a bit crazy and is too slow. If I put  all rules in only one `perl` command, it works fine.

For example, create a `perl` file **colorTail.pl** as below:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

while(<STDIN>) {
    my $line = $_;
    chomp($line);
    for($line){
        s/==>.*<==/\e[1;44m$&\e[0m/gi; #tail multiples files name in blue background
        s/.*exception.*|at .*/\e[0;31m$&\e[0m/gi;  #java errors & stacktraces in red
        s/info.*/\e[1;32m$&\e[0m/gi; #info replacement in green
        s/warning.*/\e[1;33m$&\e[0m/gi; #warning replacement in yellow
    }
    print $line, "\n";
}
```

Use it as:

```
tail -f *.log | perl colorTail.pl
tail -f *.log -f **/*.log | perl colorTail.pl
```

NOTE: you can use it on *MobaXTerm* too! Just download `perl` plug-in from *MobaXTerm* site.

Answer (score 4):

```
tail -f /var/log/logname | source-highlight -f esc -s log
```

Comment: `source-highlight` isn't a widely installed command, so you should at least give a link to the project site.

Comment: Available in Fedora 19.

Comment: And Ubuntu 12.10.

Comment: It looks nice. Its a big package compared to others in this list (26MB). It supports a huge list of languages. It can be customized modifying the config files located at: /usr/share/source-highlight/*.lang (Ubuntu). If you need something simple, go with ccze or colortail.

Comment: looks like it depends on boost, which is around 462MB

Comment: I checked all solutions above. This is the best. It is simple, and not buggy. For example, multitail provides scrolling in separate window but already without highlighting. Colortail can't work with big log files - it gives error.

Answer (score 3):

One solution that works for coloring all sorts of text, not just logfiles, is a Python tool, '[colout](http://nojhan.github.io/colout/)'.

```
pip install colout
myprocess | colout REGEX_WITH_GROUPS color1,color2... [attr1,attr2...]
```

Where any text in the output of 'myprocess' which matches group 1 of the regex will be colored with color1, group 2 with color2, etc.

For example:

```
tail -f /var/log/mylogfile | colout '^(\w+ \d+ [\d:]+)|(\w+\.py:\d+ .+\(\)): (.+)$' white,black,cyan bold,bold,normal
```

i.e. the first regex group (parens) matches the initial date in the logfile, the second group matches a python filename, line number and function name, and the third group matches the log message that comes after that. This looks like:

[image: logfile with colored formatting]

Note that lines or parts of lines which don't match any of my regex are still echoed, so this isn't like 'grep --color' - nothing is filtered out of the output.

Obviously this is flexible enough that you can use it with any process, not just tailing logfiles. I usually just whip up a new regex on the fly any time I want to colorize something. For this reason, I prefer colout to any custom logfile-coloring tool, because I only need to learn one tool, regardless of what I'm coloring: logging, test output, syntax highlighting snippets of code in the terminal, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Shameless plug: I wrote a tool called [TxtStyle](https://github.com/armandino/TxtStyle) that does something similar as the options mentioned earlier. You can run it as follows:

```
tail -f /var/log/syslog | txts --regex '\d+'
```

You can also define named styles in the config file (`~/.txts.conf`) and use it like so:

```
ifconfig | txts --name ifconfig
```

(`ifconfig` style is defined out of the box)

Answer (score 2):

As for the color codes, I would use tput:

```
red=$( tput -Txterm setaf 1 )
norm=$( tput -Txterm sgr0 )
bold=$( tput -Txterm bold )
```

See for reference: `man tput`

Then:

```
tail -F myfile.log | sed "s/\(.ERROR.*\)/$red$bold\1$norm/g"
```

Answer (score 2):

**grc for sure!**

customize your collors with regex in the file: ~.grc/conf.tail (or whatever name you want)

```
regexp=.*(select .*)$
colours=unchanged,cyan
=====
regexp=.*(update .*)$
colours=unchanged,bold yellow
=====
regexp=.*(insert .*)$
colours=unchanged,bold yellow
=====
regexp=.*(emp=\d+).*
colours=unchanged,reverse green
=====
regexp=.*http.*/rest/contahub.cmds.(.*?)/(\w*).*$
colours=unchanged,green,magenta
=====
regexp=.*http.*/M/.*\.(.*?Facade)/(\w*).*$
colours=unchanged,underline green,underline magenta
```

command line:

```
grc -c conf.tail tail -f log/tomcat/catalina.out
```

results:
[image: screenshot]

info for configuring grc:
https://github.com/manjuraj/config/blob/master/.grc/sample.conf

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a bash function that accepts up to three parameters and does a grep-like filter on a text file, and outputs text to the screen in color.

I would also like to see a tail function that would do this, but haven't found one yet.

This function can also be improved - I'd appreciate any help on how to make it better.

```
function multigrep(){

    #THIS WORKS - Recreate this, using input parameters
    #sed -En '/(App)|(Spe)/p' ./flashlog.txt;

    filename="/Users/stevewarren/Library/Preferences/Macromedia/Flash\ Player/Logs/flashlog.txt";
    paramString="";

    for element in "$@"
        do
            #echo $element;
            paramString="$paramString($element)|";
        done

    #TRIM FINAL | OFF PARAMSTRING
    paramString=${paramString:0:${#paramString}-1};

    #CREATE SED EXPRESSION - '/($1)|($2)|(...)/p'
    paramString="'/$paramString/p'";

    #CREATE SED FUNCTION, CALL ON FILE
    paramString="sed -En $paramString ./flashlog.txt"

    echo $paramString;
    echo "${txtbld}$(tput setaf 7)" > ./flashlog_output.txt;
    eval $paramString >> ./flashlog_output.txt;
    echo >> ./flashlog_output.txt;
    #cat ./flashlog_output.txt;

    cat ./flashlog_output.txt | while read LINE
    do

        [[  $1 && ${1-x} ]] && 
            if grep -q $1 <<<$LINE; then
                echo "$(tput setaf 3)$LINE"
            fi

        [[  $2 && ${2-x} ]] && 
            if grep -q $2 <<<$LINE; then
                echo "$(tput setaf 7)$LINE"
            fi


        [[  $3 && ${3-x} ]] && 
            if grep -q $3 <<<$LINE; then
                echo "$(tput setaf 6)$LINE"
            fi

    done
}
```

Answer (score 1):

sure !

I wrote long a go a function called "egrepi", based on the 8 color variables definitions.
This works ONLY piped like a "tail -f" colored function.

**1. setColors**

first, the color variables function to be called at first:

```
setColors ()
{
set -a
which printf >/dev/null 2>&1 && print=printf || print=print # Mandriva doesn't know about printf

hide='eval tput civis'
show='eval tput cnorm'
CLS=$(tput clear)
bel=$(tput bel)

case ${UNAME} in
AIX)
# text / foreground
N=$(${print} '\033[1;30m')
n=$(${print} '\033[0;30m')
R=$(${print} '\033[1;31m')
r=$(${print} '\033[0;31m')
G=$(${print} '\033[1;32m')
g=$(${print} '\033[0;32m')
Y=$(${print} '\033[1;33m')
y=$(${print} '\033[0;33m')
B=$(${print} '\033[1;34m')
b=$(${print} '\033[0;34m')
M=$(${print} '\033[1;35m')
m=$(${print} '\033[0;35m')
C=$(${print} '\033[1;36m')
c=$(${print} '\033[0;36m')
W=$(${print} '\033[1;37m')
w=$(${print} '\033[0;37m')
END=$(${print} '\033[0m')

# background
RN=$(${print} '\033[6;40m')
Rn=$(${print} '\033[40m')
RR=$(${print} '\033[6;41m')
Rr=$(${print} '\033[41m')
RG=$(${print} '\033[6;42m')
Rg=$(${print} '\033[42m')
RY=$(${print} '\033[6;43m')
Ry=$(${print} '\033[43m')
RB=$(${print} '\033[6;44m')
Rb=$(${print} '\033[44m')
RM=$(${print} '\033[6;45m')
Rm=$(${print} '\033[45m')
RC=$(${print} '\033[6;46m')
Rc=$(${print} '\033[46m')
RW=$(${print} '\033[6;47m')
Rw=$(${print} '\033[47m')

HIGH=$(tput bold)
SMUL=$(tput smul)
RMUL=$(tput rmul)
BLINK=$(tput blink)
REVERSE=$(tput smso)
REVERSO=$(tput rmso)
;;
*)
# text / foreground
n=$(tput setaf 0)
r=$(tput setaf 1)
g=$(tput setaf 2)
y=$(tput setaf 3)
b=$(tput setaf 4)
m=$(tput setaf 5)
c=$(tput setaf 6)
w=$(tput setaf 7)
N=$(tput setaf 8)
R=$(tput setaf 9)
G=$(tput setaf 10)
Y=$(tput setaf 11)
B=$(tput setaf 12)
M=$(tput setaf 13)
C=$(tput setaf 14)
W=$(tput setaf 15)
END=$(tput sgr0)

HIGH=$(tput bold)
SMUL=$(tput smul)
RMUL=$(tput rmul)
BLINK=$(tput blink)
REVERSE=$(tput smso)
REVERSO=$(tput rmso)

# background
Rn=$(tput setab 0)
Rr=$(tput setab 1)
Rg=$(tput setab 2)
Ry=$(tput setab 3)
Rb=$(tput setab 4)
Rm=$(tput setab 5)
Rc=$(tput setab 6)
Rw=$(tput setab 7)
RN=$(tput setab 8)
RR=$(tput setab 9)
RG=$(tput setab 10)
RY=$(tput setab 11)
RB=$(tput setab 12)
RM=$(tput setab 13)
RC=$(tput setab 14)
RW=$(tput setab 15)
;;
esac

BLUEf=${B}
BLUE=${b}
REDf=${R}
RED=${r}
GREENf=${G}
GREEN=${g}
YELLOWf=${Y}
YELLOW=${y}
MANGENTAf=${M}
MANGENTA=${m}
WHITEf=${W}
WHITE=${w}
CYANf=${C}
CYAN=${c}

OK="${RG}${n}OK${END}"
KO="${RR}${n}KO${END}"
NA="${N}NA${END}"

COLORIZE='eval sed -e "s/{END}/${END}/g" -e "s/{HIGH}/${HIGH}/g" -e "s/{SMUL}/${SMUL}/g" -e "s/{RMUL}/${RMUL}/g" -e "s/{BLINK}/${BLINK}/g" -e "s/{REVERSE}/${REVERSE}/g" -e "s/{REVERSO}/${REVERSO}/g"'
LOWS=' -e "s/{n}/${n}/g" -e "s/{r}/${r}/g" -e "s/{g}/${g}/g" -e "s/{y}/${y}/g" -e "s/{b}/${b}/g" -e "s/{m}/${m}/g" -e "s/{c}/${c}/g" -e "s/{w}/${w}/g"'
HIGHS=' -e "s/{N}/${N}/g" -e "s/{R}/${R}/g" -e "s/{G}/${G}/g" -e "s/{Y}/${Y}/g" -e "s/{B}/${B}/g" -e "s/{M}/${M}/g" -e "s/{C}/${C}/g" -e "s/{W}/${W}/g"'
REVLOWS=' -e "s/{Rn}/${Rn}/g" -e "s/{Rr}/${Rr}/g" -e "s/{Rg}/${Rg}/g" -e "s/{Ry}/${Ry}/g" -e "s/{Rb}/${Rb}/g" -e "s/{Rm}/${Rm}/g" -e "s/{Rc}/${Rc}/g" -e "s/{Rw}/${Rw}/g"'
REVHIGHS=' -e "s/{RN}/${RN}/g" -e "s/{RR}/${RR}/g" -e "s/{RG}/${RG}/g" -e "s/{RY}/${RY}/g" -e "s/{RB}/${RB}/g" -e "s/{RM}/${RM}/g" -e "s/{RC}/${RC}/g" -e "s/{RW}/${RW}/g"'
# COLORIZE Usage:
# command |${COLORIZE} ${LOWS} ${HIGHS} ${REVLOWS} ${REVHIGHS}

set +a
}
```

**2. egrepi**

and the egrepi function, effective and elegant: color cycling between 8 or more colors (your needs) AND tested under 3 different unix OS, with comments :

```
# egrepi() egrep with 8 REVERSE cyclic colorations on regexps almost like egrep
# egrepi 
# current script will work for KSH88, KSH93, bash 2+, zsh, under AIX / Linux / SunOS
egrepi ()
{
args=$*
# colorList=wBcgymrN                                                # KSH93 or bash 3+, not for AIX
# set -A color                                                  # needed with older sh
color[0]=$Rw; color[1]=$RB; color[2]=$Rc; color[3]=$Rg; color[4]=$Ry; color[5]=$Rm; color[6]=$Rr; color[7]=$RN; # this is the only one AIX solution
i=0
unset argsToGrep argsSedColor argsPerlColor

for arg in ${args}
do
    [ "${arg}" == "." ] && arg=\\.                              # if you wanna grep "."
    # color=R${colorList:((${RANDOM: -1:1})):1}                     # bash RANDOMized colors
    # color=R${colorList:$i:1} && let i++ && ((i==8)) && i=0                # KSH93 or bash 3+, not for AIX
    argsToGrep="${argsToGrep}${argsToGrep:+|}${arg}"
    # argsSedColor="${argsSedColor} -e s#${arg}#$n${!color}&${w}#gI"            # AIX KSH88 do not recognise this fucking variable double expansion
    # argsSedColor="${argsSedColor} -e s#${arg}#$n${color[$i]}&${w}#gI"         # AIX neither do include sed with Ignore case
    argsPerlColor="${argsPerlColor}${argsPerlColor:+,}s#${arg}#$n${color[$i]}$&${END}#gi"   # So: gotta use perl
    let i+=1 && ((i==8)) && i=0                             # AIX KSH88 do not recognise "let i++"
done
# egrep -i "${argsToGrep}" | sed ${argsSedColor} | egrep -v "grep|sed"              # AIX sed incompatibility with Ignore case
# (($# > 0)) && (egrep -i "${argsToGrep}" | perl -p -e ${argsPerlColor}) || cat         # this line colors & grep the words, will NOT act as "tail -f"
(($# > 0)) && (perl -p -e ${argsPerlColor}) || cat                      # this line just colors the words
}
```

**3. Usage**

command | egrepi *word1* .. *wordN*

Answer (score 1):

You might also want to take a look at [lwatch](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/lwatch.1.html):

`tail -f /var/log/syslog | lwatch --input -`

Answer (score 1):

for Centos

```
yum install -y ccze
tail -f /var/log/file.log | ccze -A
```

Comment: FYI, ```ccze``` package is removed from centos 8 epel repo.

Answer (score 0):

Publishes some time ago Node Js utility - [log-color-highlight](https://www.npmjs.com/package/log-color-highlight)

```
tail -f file | lch -red error warn -green success
lch -f file -red.bold error warn -underline.bgGreen success
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the @[this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/169965/440785), I've created a solution which shows dynamic tail output from the multiple logs files and returns coloured warning and error messages as below:

```
tail -f -n 5 application.log debug.log| perl -pe 's#WARNING#\x1b[33m$&#; s#ERROR#\x1b[31m$&#; s#foo#\x1b[32m$&#'
```

No installation needed. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Working solution on Mac

[image: Colored logs on mac]

Tried a bunch of things that just didn't work because of some escaping issue.

Eventually found a working solution:

```
tail -f example.log | sed \
-e "s/FATAL/"$'\e[31m'"&"$'\e[m'"/" \
-e "s/ERROR/"$'\e[31m'"&"$'\e[m'"/" \
-e "s/WARNING/"$'\e[33m'"&"$'\e[m'"/" \
-e "s/INFO/"$'\e[32m'"&"$'\e[m'"/" \
-e "s/DEBUG/"$'\e[34m'"&"$'\e[m'"/"
```

A quick way to show it working:

```
echo " [timestamp] production.FATAL Some Message\n" \
"[timestamp] production.ERROR Some Message\n" \
"[timestamp] production.WARNING Some Message\n" \
"[timestamp] production.INFO Some Message\n" \
"[timestamp] production.DEBUG Some Message\n"  | sed \
-e "s/FATAL/"$'\e[31m'"&"$'\e[m'"/" \
-e "s/ERROR/"$'\e[31m'"&"$'\e[m'"/" \
-e "s/WARNING/"$'\e[33m'"&"$'\e[m'"/" \
-e "s/INFO/"$'\e[32m'"&"$'\e[m'"/" \
-e "s/DEBUG/"$'\e[34m'"&"$'\e[m'"/"
```

Note: this won't hide any logs, just color the parts needed

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Please note however that the approach of using `sed` to post-process the raw output and introduce color escape codes was already mentioned in the [answer by @Gilles](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/8419/377345). Please review your answer and decide whether your approach is sufficiently distinct to warrant a post of its own, or if it should rather be an edit to add details to the mentioned answer.

Comment: @AdminBee Thanks :) and hello. While the other question mentions using `sed`, it doesn't work on Mac, I've tried it. The start of the line gets replaced with `o033[32m` and end `o033[39m`, and its not coloured. I believe this is because the way unix escapes part of it. Ive searched high and wide for a solution to this, but nothing worked.

Answer (score 0):

```bsh
sudo apt install grc
grc tail /var/log/syslog
alias tail='grc tail'
```

[image]

Comment: This is a duplicate of [thias’ answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/21962/86440).

Comment: It really should refer to the existing answer as a basis; I see the addition of `alias tail='grc tail'` here which seems unique among the existing answers. That does address the question "What kind of alias can I setup for a `tail` command...`". Perhaps a suggested edit would have been better?

Answer (score 0):

There is a new open source tool ([Logdy.dev](https://logdy.dev)) that satisfies the need. You can use TypeScript to parse and transform the content of log messages. All of that in a web UI that comes filters/facets.

Update: you can style each individual row or cell by applying a style in a [Message](https://logdy.dev/docs/reference/code#message) or [CellHandler](https://logdy.dev/docs/reference/code#cellhandler) handler.

For example, here is a code that makes the background of a column with an `error` level cell row red. The code is applied for a `level` column.

```javascript
(line: Message): CellHandler => {
    return {
        text: line.json_content.level,
        style: {
            background: line.json_content.level === 'error' ? "red" : ""
        },
        facets: [
            { name: "Level", value: line.json_content.level }
        ]
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: (1) What does your image illustrate?  I don’t see any color (except for a tiny bit of decorative trim), so it doesn’t look like either an example of colorized output ***or*** configuration / setup.  (2) It looks like this tool produces HTML output for a web browser.  The question is tagged “command-line”.  I don’t know whether the fact that this tool is *invoked* via the command line is enough to qualify it as a valid answer.  Can it *output* to a terminal?      Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: In fact, I don't see anything on the website for this tool that suggests that it can even do what this question asks for, namely to colorize (some of) the output.

Comment: thanks, that's a fair call out, I've updated the original message.