# What's a convenient way of checking what's being added to a log file in realtime?

Tags: logs, tail

Right now I'm essentially executing `tail /var/log/syslog` manually every once in a while. Is there something that lets me see what's being added continuously, or do I need to write something myself?

Comment: This is often called “tailing”, after [`tail -f`](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12692/whats-a-convenient-way-of-checking-whats-being-added-to-a-log-file-in-realtime/12693#12693). See also [How to have tail -f show colored output](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8414/how-to-have-tail-f-show-colored-output) and more generally [the `tail` tag](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tags/tail).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe you're looking for the `-f` switch. It will continue to follow the the log file as it changes.

```
tail -f /var/log/syslog
```

You can vary the number of lines that are output using the `-n` switch as well:

```
tail -f -n 20 /var/log/syslog
```

See [man tail](http://ss64.com/bash/tail.html) for more information.

Comment: tail -f | grep ... | while read line; do ...; done is an extremely common scripting idiom among sysadmins.  (Yes variants of of it using popen() styled subprocesses count as using the same idiom).  It's used to selectively process logged events in near real-time (for example to send alerts or initiated automated remediation scripts).