# Pretty tail -f for log files

Tags: software-rec, logs, tail

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to have tail -f show colored output](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8414/how-to-have-tail-f-show-colored-output)

Is there a bash/awk script or utility that pretty formats and colors tail -f from log files? At the moment I am specifically looking at Apache log files.