# Colorizing tail output with sed

Tags: shell, sed, quoting

How would I go about colorizing the output of `tail` with `sed`?

`` echo "`tput setaf 1`foo`tput op`" `` works as expected

`` echo "foo" | sed -e 's/(foo)/`tput setaf 1`\0`tput op`/g' `` however, does not.

What am I missing here?

Comment: The reason it's not working is that backticks have no special meaning inside single quotes but they do have a special meaning inside double quotes.

Comment: Take a look at http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8414/how-to-have-tail-f-show-colored-output - it has some suggestions for colorizing output including [rainbow](https://github.com/nicoulaj/rainbow), [multitail](http://www.vanheusden.com/multitail/) and [grc](http://korpus.juls.savba.sk/~garabik/software/grc.html) which should suit your needs if `grep` does not.

Answer (score 9):

Does it have to be `sed`?

```
echo "foo bar baz" | grep --color=auto "bar"
```

The above will highlight `bar` in red by default.  The man page says you can choose what colour to use with the environment variable `GREP_COLORS`.

To make it print all lines and only highlight `bar`:

```
echo "foo bar baz" | grep -E --color=auto "^|bar"
```

Comment: +1 use the right tool for the job - there is no need to rape sed just to colorize output.

Comment: @syneticon-dj: This doesn't actually work to colour the output of tail though. It will only print lines containing "bar" (with bar highlighted) and all other lines will be left unprinted.

Comment: @Iain adding `-C <great number>` should help as a quick hack

Comment: Not worth a whole new answer, but you can also just do: `tail file | grep "pattern\|"` or `tail file | grep -E "pattern|"`, depending on your mood. ;) (Supposing you already have `--color=auto` in your `COLOR_OPTIONS` environment variable set)

Comment: Brilliant! ```tail -n 2 -f /usr/local/var/log/nginx/*.log &  tail -n 5 -f /usr/local/var/log/*.log | grep --color=auto "]"```

Answer (score 6):

The backticks `` in the echo command spawn a process and it's output is substituted into the echo command line. You can see this with e.g.

```
echo "`tput setaf 1`" | hexdump -C
00000000  1b 5b 33 31 6d 0a                       |.[31m.|
```

This works because the contents of the `"..."` are expanded before being passed to echo.

The sed command you're using wraps everything in `'` so it is passed to sed without expansion and sed sees it all as literal text.

You can fix this by putting "" around your sed command

```
echo "foo" | sed -e "s/\(foo\)/`tput setaf 1`\1`tput op`/g"
```

You also had an error in your sed command. The `(` and `)` need to be escaped `\(` and `\)` to denote the remembered pattern. I've also never use `\0` I've always used `\1` as the first remembered pattern.