# Is there some built-in (bash/gentoo) function to provide well-readable output to the user?

Tags: shell-script, logs, colors

I am using the following simple function to provide some well readable output to the user. Now I am wondering if there is some kind of (gentoo-/bash-) built-in function to accomplish this task, as this feels like 're-inventing' the wheel. Thanks in advance.

```bsh
function log
{
        red='\033[0;31m'
        green='\033[0;32m'
        yellow='\033[1;33m'
        term='\033[0m'

        if [ "$1" == "INFO" ]; then
                echo -e "${green}[i] $2 ${term}"
        elif [ "$1" == "WARN" ]; then
                echo -e "${yellow}[w] $2 ${term}"
        elif [ "$1" == "ERROR" ]; then
                echo -e "${red}[e] $2 ${term}"
        fi
}
```

Comment: You are reinventing the wheel.  See my answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to have tail -f show colored output](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8414/how-to-have-tail-f-show-colored-output)

Comment: Thanks for all the replies. I guess my question was kind of misleading. I am not trying to acutally log to a file - I am simply trying to provide well-readable (colorfull) output to stdout.

Comment: I think maybe you want `$PS[1234]`?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what are you trying to achieve, but if your function will somehow interact with portage then perhaps you could use its color definition. From `man 5 color.map`:

```
VARIABLES
       NORMAL = "normal"
              Defines color used for some words  occuring  in  other  contexts  than  those
              below.

       BAD = "red"
              Defines color used for some words occuring in bad context.

       BRACKET = "blue"
              Defines color used for brackets.

       GOOD = "green"
              Defines color used for some words occuring in good context.

       HILITE = "teal"
              Defines color used for highlighted words.

       INFORM = "darkgreen"
              Defines color used for informational words.

       [...]

       SECURITY_WARN = "red"
              Defines color used for security warnings.

       UNMERGE_WARN = "red"
              Defines color used for unmerge warnings.

       WARN = "yellow"
          Defines color used for warnings.
```

Answer (score 1):

There are no built-in function to colourize logs, but there's

- Vim with its `messages` highlighter that makes logs easier to read and also highlights lines with certain keywords ("error", "failed", etc.) in red.
  Try `:setf messages`.
- *`ccze` - A robust log colorizer* — a replacement for `colorize` that apparently has lots of ways to customize it colourization features.
- `colortail`, which *"is basically tail but with support for colors."*
- and a bunch of other tools — see [this question](//unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8414/how-to-have-tail-f-show-colored-output) for some more

Answer (score 0):

Consider Enabling Portage ELogging.

Taken from the [Gentoo Wiki: Portage Log](http://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Portage_log).

Inside `/etc/portage/make.conf`:

1. Set `PORT_LOGDIR`, i.e.
   `PORT_LOGDIR="/var/log/portage"`
2. Set `PORTAGE_ELOG_CLASSES`, i.e.
   `PORTAGE_ELOG_CLASSES="log warn error"`
3. Set `PORTAGE_ELOG_SYSTEM`, i.e.
   `PORTAGE_ELOG_SYSTEM="save"`

You can also set Option 3 differently depending on your needs.

> For mailing logs to some recipient, you should enable the mail module
>   instead, and set some additional variables, too. Please read
>   /usr/share/portage/config/make.conf.example for details.