# sed - find correct color sequence for ANSI extended 256 colors

Tags: sed, colors

I am currently using the following command to use the standard ANSI colors with the tail command:

```
tail -f syslogfile | sed -e 's/\(.*MAJOR.*\)/\o033[93m\1\o033[39m/'
```

This is bright yellow however I am just getting into extended 256 colors in bash and I would like to use the color orange. I have found the correct foreground and background color numbering scheme to give me orange on black.

```
echo -e "\\033[40;5;95;38;5;202mhello world\\033[0m"
```

However I am having trouble translating this into a sed command that I can use with the tail command.

I have tried this:

```
sed -e 's/\(.*MAJOR.*\)/\033[40;5;95;38;5;202\033[0m/'
```

But that leaves everything white. I have tried:

```
sed -e 's/\(.*MAJOR.*\)/\o033[40;5;95;38;5;202\o033[0m/'
```

But this blacks out the lines that contain the string "MAJOR". I have also tried leaving out the background scheme and just going with the orange :

```
sed -e 's/\(.*MAJOR.*\)/\033[38;5;202\033[0m/'
```

But this also seems to black out the lines that contain the word "MAJOR"
Does anyone know what the correct ANSI sequence would be for sed to give me orange on black? FYI the sed command I used in my first example prints the entire line in the color chosen and I would need the same behavior with the new color sequence, not just coloring the word itself.

UPDATE:

This works:

```
sed -e 's/\(.*MINOR.*\)/\o033[38;5;202m\1\o033[40;5;95m/'
```

But leaves other lines that do not contain MINOR colored magenta. How do I get those to default back to white. Am I not turning something off correctly? It's actually making default font color for the entire shell magenta, as I can see when I terminate the tail command.

Comment: there are several programs that already do colour highlighting of log files etc, and there are several questions on this site about them.  e.g. see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8414/how-to-have-tail-f-show-colored-output - and the Linked and Related questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably looking for this:

```
sed -e 's/\(.*MAJOR.*\)/\o033[48;5;95;38;5;202m\1\o033[0m/'
```

although it can be simplified with

```
sed -e 's/.*MAJOR.*/\o033[48;5;95;38;5;202m&\o033[m/'
```

Notice change of `40` to `48` what means we want to change background color.

If you want background color as black:

```
sed -e 's/.*MAJOR.*/\o033[40;38;5;202m&\o033[m/'
```

and if background color is already black you don't need to change it at all:

```
sed -e 's/.*MAJOR.*/\o033[38;5;202m&\o033[m/'
```

Comment: You had it right the first time - 40;5;95m. Using 48;5;95 gives a light orange transparent background.

Comment: Put simply I just want lines with MAJOR colored orange with a black background.

Comment: thanks for teaching me about `&` vs. `\1`. +1

Comment: @user53029 Then I don't understand why did you put `40,5,95` code. It changes background color to black, then add blinking (rarely supported by terminals), then change foreground color to high intensity and then once again change foreground color - this doesn't make sense to me. Anyhow added some more examples to the answer.

Comment: Yea, I'm new to all this 256 bash color stuff.

Answer (score 3):

There is more than one problem, seen by making a script of your examples:

```
#!/bin/sh
MSG="this is MAJOR stuff"
echo "$MSG" | sed -e 's/\(.*MAJOR.*\)/\o033[93m\1\o033[39m/'
echo "$MSG" | sed -e 's/\(.*MAJOR.*\)/\033[40;5;95;38;5;202\033[0m/'
echo "$MSG" | sed -e 's/\(.*MAJOR.*\)/\o033[40;5;95;38;5;202\o033[0m/'
echo "$MSG" | sed -e 's/\(.*MAJOR.*\)/\033[38;5;202\033[0m/'
```

which produces (`^[` is escape):

```
^[[93mthis is MAJOR stuff^[[39m
this is MAJOR stuff33[40;5;95;38;5;202this is MAJOR stuff33[0m
^[[40;5;95;38;5;202^[[0m
this is MAJOR stuff33[38;5;202this is MAJOR stuff33[0m
```

In the first line, a `^[[93m` is the aixterm 16-color escape to set a yellow text, and `^39m` resets text to the terminal's default colors.

The second line has problems with an unterminated escape sequence (that starts off setting background to black=40, blink=5, 95=bright magenta text, then 38 and 5 try to introduce a 256-color sequence -- which is not terminated).

The third line is a slight variation of the second.

The main problem is that your `sed` does not emit an escape character unless you express it as `\o033` (which you *did* do in a few places).

Second, you are not ending the escapes properly.  That final `m` is part of the sequence.  When the final character is missing, the entire sequence can be discarded. It's best to read the documentation: [XTerm Control Sequences](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html).

By the way, **ANSI** never documented anything past 8 colors, so it's less confusing to refer to the sequences by the original implementation (aixterm for 16-colors, xterm for 256-colors).

If you simply want entire lines with *MAJOR* to be highlighted in orange, then (based on comments), you could have done this:

```
sed -e 's/^\(.*MAJOR.*\)$/\o033[48;5;95m\1\o033[m/'
```

However, the `5` code is less widely supported than the `2` using R/G/B, something like this:

```
sed -e 's/^\(.*MAJOR.*\)$/\o033[48;2;128;128;0m\1\o033[m/'
```

(the 128's are just a first try - your tastes can vary).

Further reading:

- [ECMA-48: Control Functions for Coded Character Sets](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-048.htm)
- [Can I set a color by its number?](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html#color_by_number) (xterm FAQ)
- [XTerm Control Sequences](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html)
  In particular, the section beginning with

> [`CSI Pm m  Character Attributes (SGR).`](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h4-Functions-using-CSI-_-ordered-by-the-final-character-lparen-s-rparen:CSI-Pm-m.1CA7)

Comment: Nice writeup up with lots of info to research for OP and others, but no fixed `sed -e '...' ` solution for OP. ;)  +1