# How to highlight entire line on matching a word within the line in egrep?

Tags: grep, colors, highlighting

Currently, I use

```
egrep --color 'error|$'
```

to highlight every word in a line containing the word error:

[image]

I would like to highlight the entire line though so that the entire string appears in red.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: @don_crissti I also want to see the lines not matching the pattern.

Comment: yeah, I got it... see the suggested duplicate and also [How to have tail -f show colored output](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/8414)

Comment: `grep -E --color '.*error.*|^'`

Comment: @Costas Exaclty what I was looking for. Please provide as answer, bonus point for explaining why it does what it does :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To highlight the complete line, you should expand the regex so that it includes all (if any) characters before and after the desired term. Do this by prepending and appending `.*` to the term being searched for:

```
echo "foo bar error baz" | egrep --color '.*error.*|$'
```

Comment: This will hide the other content not matching the pattern. I want to keep it.

Comment: @k0pernikus Sorry, I omitted the `|$` in the regex while testing. I've fixed that now.